# Proving this formula using Layer-cake representation

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $K > 0$ be a fixed positive parameter and let us consider the set $\Sigma_{N} := \{-1,+1\}^{N}$, for $N \ge 1$. Given two elements $x = (x_{i})_{i=1}^{N}, y= (y_{i})_{i=1}^{N} \in \Sigma_{N}$, I will write $\langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}y_{i}$. Consider the following identity:
$$\sum_{x \in \Sigma_{N}}\frac{1}{2^{N}}e^{\frac{1}{2}KN \langle x,y\rangle^{2}} = 1 + \int_{0}^{1}dt NKt e^{Kt^{2}}p_{0}(|\langle x,y\rangle| \ge t), $$
where $p_{0}$ denotes the probability measure with respect to Bernoulli random variables.

I saw this formula in a seminar, and I wrote it down. I am now trying to understand where it comes from. The lecturer mentioned that it comes from the layer-cake representation. I had never heard about it before the talk. Then, I searched on the internet and I found some formulas, but none of them seems to help get the above identity proven. Maybe you could help me prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the following fact:

> Let $X$ be a positive random variable and $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f(X)$ is integrable and $f'$ is non-negative. Then, $$\Bbb E[f(X)] = f(0) + \int_0^{\infty} f'(t)P(X\geq t)\,dt.$$

The proof of this fact relies on Tonelli's theorem and can be summarized as follows:

Let $P_X$ be the distribution measure of $X$, i.e. $P_X(A) = P(X \in A)$. Then
$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[f(X)] &= \int f(X(\omega)) \,dP(\omega) = \int f(x)\,dP_X(x) = \int \left(f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt\right)\,dP_X(x)\\&=f(0) + \int_0^\infty f'(t) \int \mathbb{1}_{t\leq x} \,dP_X\, dt=f(0)+\int_0^{\infty} f'(t)P(X\geq t)\,dt\end{align*}$$

The result still holds if we replace the non-negative derivative assumption with the assumption that $\int \int_0^x |f'(t)|\,dt\,d P_X(x) < \infty$ (so Fubini's theorem applies).

What you want to prove is now just an application of the above on the space $(\Sigma_N, \mathcal{P}(\Sigma_N), p_0)$ where $p_0$ is the discrete uniform measure on $\Sigma_N$ which is equivalent to the probability measure wrt $N$ independent symmetric Bernoulli random variables, $X$ is the random variable $|\langle x, y \rangle |$ and $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2}KNx^2}$. In this particular case, Tonelli's theorem is not really needed as you would only need to interchange a finite sum with an integral.